# Check first line of multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net

I would like to check under _KeyDown handler of textbox if cursor is on first (top) line of multiline textbox.

For example:

```
If IsInTopLine(TextBox1) Then SelectNextControl TextBox1, False, True, True, True
```

I would also like to know cursor is on last line of such textbox.

Actually, I would like to get advice on how to make IsInTopLine and IsInBottomLine functions.

EDIT:
No need for help.
I just find ".GetLineFromCharIndex" function :)